# Upon reactivating a recurring profile, can I specify a new starting payment number?

Tags: api, paypal, recurring, nvp

I am using PayPal's NVP and Reports APIs to manage recurring profiles.  Is there any way to specify a new starting recurring payment number when reactivating a profile previously canceled by my software (not canceled by PayPal)?  Currently, when paypal performs the first recurring payment after reactivation, it assigns the payment number of the most recently declined recurring payment for that new payment.  The declined payment could have been for the current month, or any number of months ago.  I would like to make it increment to the next number for the initial payment after reactivation.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that you could call [UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/) and set `OUTSTANDINGAMT` to 0.00. I'm not totally sure that would fix it, though.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you are not able to do that, but you could pass a custom variable using NOTE in the UpdateRecurringPaymentProfile.